# How to get user history from OS maps API?

Tags: openstreetmap, api

Is there a way to get the history of a user as found on the [OS maps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/m%20ahmed/history#map=10/25.2125/67.0167)

[image]

by using the OS maps API? https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/user/8566797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OSM API using [changesets API endpoint](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Query:_GET_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fchangesets)

To illustrate for your user, you can use either:

- To get result by user name https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/changesets?display_name=m%20ahmed
- To get result by user identifier https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/changesets?user=8566797

You can browse aditional options mentioned in the first link provided

Comment: Thanks to @ThomasG77

Comment: Looks like this call returns at most 100 changesets. Do you if you can change any parameters to get all the records?

Comment: You may play with date https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/23089/how-to-query-all-changesets-by-a-user-since-eternity but be careful or you will be banned for abuse. If you want more changesets related infos, you should consider using a PostGIS database using the following data and recipe to import into database https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Changeset#Changeset_Dump

Comment: Great, thank you very much @ThomasG77